# How to make Bimap an instance of SafeCopy?

Tags: haskell, serialization, typeclass

When I recently tried to serialize a data structure in which I used 
Data.Bimap, I encountered the problem that Bimap is not an instance of
SafeCopy.

Now, after having a look in Data.SafeCopy.Instances, I came up with the
following:

```
instance (SafeCopy a, SafeCopy b, Ord a, Ord b) => SafeCopy (Bimap a b) where
    getCopy = contain $ fmap fromAscPairList safeGet
    putCopy = contain . safePut . toAscList
```

This compiles but I have no idea whether it does the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SafeCopy part of your implementation is correct, but there is an issue with the Bimap part. The problem is that `toAscList` and `fromAscPairList` have different requirements. In the [documentation for bimap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bimap-0.2.4/docs/Data-Bimap.html) the following is stated about these functions:

**toAscList:**

*Convert to a list of associated pairs, **with the left-hand values** in ascending order.*

**fromAscPairList:**

*Build a bimap from a list of pairs, **where both the fst and snd halves of the list** are in strictly ascending order.*

So toAscList will build a list where the left side values are in order, while fromAscPairList requires both values to be in order. So your implementation will cause a runtime-error when you try to deserialize a map where both values don't have the same ordering. Here is an example:

```
> fromAscPairList $ toAscList $ fromList [(1,3),(2,2)]
fromList *** Exception: Data.Bimap.fromAscPairList: list not correctly ascending
```

You can fix this issue by replacing `toAscList` with `toList` and `fromAscPairList` with `fromList`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess `toAscList` etc are usually used for performance reasons?

Comment: Yes, `fromAscList` is usually faster (for `Data.Map` and `Data.Set`) because the datastructures are ordered. `toAscList` is usually not faster than `toList` because if it was, they would just use the same implementation, since `toList` doesn't make any promises about its ordering.